# How to survive Purim

Tags: purim, how-to

How do you survive a very busy Purim?

Purim is a very interactive holiday and has a number of Mitzvot that need to be observed that intersect with, and are often dependent on, other people's activities and their own fulfillment of the Mitzvot.

What are some helpful strategies, tactics, and plans for keeping it all together and not only fulfilling the obligations but keeping the holiday festive and enjoyable for all involved?

Comment: Could you please [edit] this question to be much clearer?

Comment: @IsaacMoses How does it look to you now?

Comment: @SethJ, thanks for trying to help. Now, it reads like a collection of potential specific questions, wrapped together at the end with one overbroad question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I think it's one question asking for a plan for dealing with all the distinct, but connected, moving parts.

Comment: @IsaacMoses How about now?

Comment: I would need an example of "dependent on, other people's activities and their own fulfillment of the Mitzvot."

Answer (score 5):

You didn't explain quite what the challenges are, so I'll make some assumptions.  Correct me if I am wrong.    To some extent, the major challenge to Purim is time-management.

The first thing to help with this is planning.  Sit down with your spouse and children if the latter are of an age to be involved in the decision making process.  Plan out who is going to megilla reading when (do you and your spouse want to go together or seperately, who will take a car if you share, etc).  Plan out when and where you will have your meal.  When and where will mincha be said by anyone who wants to say it.  I'd say fit in distribution of matanot l'evyonim and mishloach manot around those things.  (This may be easier said than done).  Planning ahead helps reduce the stress of trying to do too much on the day of Purim itself, or making decisions after one may have begun to imbibe.

The second piece of advice I have is that as in many areas, people go overboard.  The meal does not need to take forever or include 12 courses.  One does not need to give mishloach manot to every person in the neighborhood.  Giving two foods to one person suffices.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1. Re "fit in distribution of matanot l'evyonim": many (all?) Jewish communities have funds for _matanos laevyonim_: you can give the money before _Purim_, making the fund manager your agent to distribute the _matanos_ on _Purim_. This saves you time and makes it so you need not know who needs the funds (a good way to give charity in general, and easier on you).

Comment: Many communities do make things work that way.  In case the OP is not in such a community, or someone else reading isn't, it is something that can take some time on the day of.  Plus, often there are people collecting on the day of Purim as well.